# react native error while installing react-native-razorpay

Tags: react-native, razorpay

can anyone help me with this error...im getting this error while installing the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-razorpay v- 2.8.8 "react": "17.0.2", and "react-native": "0.67.1",

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: easylab@0.0.1
> npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16.5.0" from react-native-razorpay@2.2.8
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-razorpay
> npm ERR!   react-native-razorpay@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\afsha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\afsha\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-12T08_50_50_495Z-debug.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically installing peer dependencies is an exciting new feature introduced in npm 7. In previous versions of npm (4-6), peer dependencies conflicts presented a warning that versions were not compatible, but would still install dependencies without an error. npm 7 will block installations if an upstream dependency conflict is present that cannot be automatically resolved.

You have the option to retry with --force to bypass the conflict or --legacy-peer-deps command to ignore peer dependencies entirely (this behavior is similar to versions 4-6)

Try install with

```
npm install react-native-razorpay --force
```

or

```
npm install react-native-razorpay --legacy-peer-deps
```