# NPM error when building getting dependency error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have tried to look up and read up about peer dependencies with npm but this error im getting is confusing me enough. Could anyone help me figure what package is causing this problem? I tried to follow everything from the bottom up but im getting lost every time.

Here is the error:

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: next-sanity-image@3.2.1
remote:        npm ERR! Found: @sanity/client@3.3.2
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
remote:        npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^3.3.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^3.2.0" from @sanity/types@2.29.5
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@sanity/types
remote:        npm ERR!     @sanity/types@"^2.0.1" from @sanity/groq-store@0.3.1
remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/@sanity/groq-store
remote:        npm ERR!       @sanity/groq-store@"^0.3.1" from next-sanity@0.5.2
remote:        npm ERR!       node_modules/next-sanity
remote:        npm ERR!         next-sanity@"^0.5.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   1 more (next-sanity)
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/next-sanity-image
remote:        npm ERR!   next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sanity/client@2.23.2
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client
remote:        npm ERR!   peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/next-sanity-image
remote:        npm ERR!     next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.2",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "get-youtube-id": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-sanity": "^0.5.2",
    "next-sanity-image": "^3.2.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.1",
    "react-portable-text": "^0.4.3",
    "react-youtube": "^9.0.3",
    "sharp": "^0.30.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.35",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.2"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    ".next/cache"
  ],
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "main": "next.config.js",
  "author": "hey",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages) gives more info on the error you're facing

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and `package.lock` file and run `npm install` again

Comment: Hey thanks. I am still getting an error, however its a different dependency error

Comment: @cheekyprogrammer Have you tried reinstalling the package in question? `npm remove package-name` and `npm install package-name`

Comment: is it complaining about the @sanity/client package? thats what im getting from that error. just checking. thx.

Comment: @cheekyprogrammer Could you add your `package.json` content to the question?

Comment: i just edited the post with the error im getting on the remote side plus the package.json. thanks!

Comment: @cheekyprogrammer You have ran `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` right?

Comment: yes. to clarify, i can get this to run for me in dev mode (npm run dev) but when its building it remotely (im pushing it to heroku) im getting this error building it

Comment: Are you pushing your .lock file and node_modules folder?

Comment: node_modules/ is in the .gitignore file but not the lock file. should i add the lock file?

Comment: Yes, do it. Heroku should find the peer dependencies itself

Comment: unfortunately its still doing the same error after ignoring the lockfile. im trying to come up with a list of packages but im not seeing where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

first you disconnect your web server after then you install your npm packages if that is not work, your packages is not support in your versio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).