# npm ci fails in Github Action

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-install, npm-ci

I am working on a pipeline to install npm packages using GitHub Actions, I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-09-09T06_53_34_562Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My pipeline looks like this :

```
name: Veracode frontend Scan
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  veracode:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16
    - run: npm ci
```

If anyone can help me out, I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618153/10403061 for another possible fix.

Answer (score 2):

Check first if this is related to [`actions/setup-node` issue 498](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/498) or [PR 103](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/pull/103)

The [`npm-ci` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) does mention:

> The main differences between using `npm install` and `npm ci` are:
>
> - The project must have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - ...

Make sure:

- your `npm` project does [create a `package-lock.json`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/pull/103#issuecomment-889874788) (which it should by default)
- it is not ignored (`.gitignore`) and is part of your repository codebase.

As [noted here](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/pull/103#issuecomment-890361838):

> Running `npm install` for a CI/CD is fundamentally flawed.
> It might be acceptable for running tests, but if you rely on *reproducible* results, you cannot and must not use `npm install`.
>
> The problem is that `npm install` will choose whatever version is the newest and that still matches your semver range specified in `package.json`.
> This often works well for some time, but if you suddenly get burned by a broken dependency introduced through a patch release, you potentially will spend hours trying to figure out which exact version you used before.
>
> Without a `package-lock.json` you have zero traceability and virtually no chance of reproducing the exact previous build ever again.
> Quite frankly, anybody suggested otherwise never had to deal with a broken production build because a fricking dev dependency broke on the CI/CD side.

---

The [OP learner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19979471/learner) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697671/nvm-not-installed-on-github-action/73698379#comment130158118_73698379) a path issue:

> The problem was that I had been running the command in the wrong directory, once I switched that where the `package-lock.json` was and it was fine.

But the error message becomes:

```
UPSTREAM ERROR 

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with 
--force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) 
dependency resolution
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72614108/6309), a `npm ci --force` is one way to go forward in that case.

Comment: I had resolved that error but rather got an UPSTREAM ERROR that says, 'Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution', I tried it with these flags but still the same error.

Comment: @learner How did you resolve the error?

Comment: The problem was that I had been running the command in the wrong directory, once I switched that where the package-lock.json was and it was fine.

Comment: @learner OK, I have edited the answer to address your second error message.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you miss to checkout the code first, just add the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) step, as example:

```
name: Veracode frontend Scan
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  veracode:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16
    - run: npm ci
```

Comment: I had resolved that error but rather got an UPSTREAM ERROR that says, 'Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution', I tried it with these flags but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> This issue may be arise when we delete the existing package-lock.json
> or when we update the node version and to do that we delete the
> existing package-lock.json. It may happen with any pipeline(Azure,
> github action etc.).
>
> So the solution you may try to run commands in:

```
install npm
npm ci
```

> If it does not fix then and you are update the nodejs version run
> below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs # install whatever nodejs version you want

npm install -g nodemon@latest
```