# Unable to install node_modules in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm try to install `node_modules` from package.json file but i got error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nfttoken@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@5.13.15
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"^5.13.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^4.1.12" from mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose-auto-increment
npm ERR!   mongoose-auto-increment@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My package json dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",
    "mongoose-sequence": "^5.3.1",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.6.1",
    "xml2json": "^0.12.0"
  }
```

how can i solve this.

**EDIT:**

I just run `npm install` i got below errors.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path <PROJECT-PATH>backend/node_modules/node-expat
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-1e860795.sh
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '<PROJECT-PATH>backend/node_modules/node-expat/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '<HOME-PATH>.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=<HOME-PATH>.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=<HOME-PATH>.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=<PROJECT-PATH>backend/node_modules/node-expat',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd <PROJECT-PATH>backend/node_modules/node-expat
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: Is the package.json latest or someone else created the package.json with some old node version. Asking because I faced similar issue as the project was created back in 2018 and downgrading my node version to 12 fixed the issue

Comment: @AnveegSinha I thing its old project. almost 3 years passed.

Comment: Then I believe downgrading node version will help. You can use nvm to switch between node versions easily

Comment: @AnveegSinha Hi, I install every package manually everything installed without errors except ```xml2json```. how can i install in node v16.17,0

Comment: that package was last updated 3 years back, so there are chances it might not work with the latest nodejs. I am not sure but downgrading will be a better and easier solution

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnveegSinha I omit ```xml2json``` lib. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the error? That `mongoose-auto-increment` library requires version 4 of `mongoose`, but you have `mongoose` 5.

You can see if things might work by adding one of the options suggested in the error, i.e. `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` or `npm i --force`, or you might want to look for a newer versionf of `mongoose-auto-increment` that claims support for Mongoose 5 (though that seems to be unlikely, since that last version of that library was released 7 years ago).

Comment: i tried ```npm install --force``` but i got same things. ```npm i --legacy-peer-deps``` too not works.

Comment: Well, then you should probably look for a supported alternative for `mongoose-auto-increment`, or lower your version of `mongoose` to 4.x.

Comment: ok i will downgrade my ```mongoose``` version.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please remove node_modules folder from the root of your project?

Then try to run

> npm install

If this is still the problem. Try removing node_modules folder again and run

> npm i --legacy-peer-deps

If this still not works, try to downgrade/upgrade the package mongoose-auto-increment

I hope those steps will work. Let me know this problem still persits.

Comment: i dont have ```node_modules```.

Comment: Okey. Would you please run npm install and see what happens?

Comment: I edit my question. i got some other kinda errors,

Comment: Okey! Do you have python installed on your system ? And may I know the version of it ?

Comment: yes i have ```Python 3.8.10```

Comment: Okey. Would you please run this command: 
npm install -g node-gyp@latest npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3.8"  ?

Here, you need to set your python folder route as config of the node-gyp.

Comment: I got this error ```ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/usr/bin/python3.8/package.json'```

Comment: Please remove the portion "/package.json" with the command. Only add "/usr/bin/python3.8" this . 

So, the command will be: npm install -g node-gyp@latest npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3.8"

May I know if you have tried this ?

Comment: yes, I didn't add ```/package.json```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248345/discussion-between-md-fahim-hossen-and-dazil).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing the same issue.

One(or more) dependency in the package.json is not compatible with the latest version of nodejs.

1. easy solution - downgrade to lower versions of nodejs using nvm
2. extra work but better solution - install all the dependencies one-by-one and find the package that is causing the error and find the latest alternative for that package