# NPM Error: Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM Packages (Cloud Function)

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I just updated firebase functions with this function `npm i firebase-functions@latest`, and updated `npm install -g firebase-tools`. And suddenly I have unabled to deploy all of my functions at `firebase deploy --only functions`. I got all of these errors:

> ```
> Build failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: firebase-functions-test@0.2.3
> npm ERR! Found: firebase-functions@4.0.0-rc.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-functions
> npm ERR!   firebase-functions@"^4.0.0-rc.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer firebase-functions@">=2.0.0" from firebase-functions-test@0.2.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-functions-test
> npm ERR!   dev firebase-functions-test@"^0.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: firebase-functions@3.24.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-functions
> npm ERR!   peer firebase-functions@">=2.0.0" from firebase-functions-test@0.2.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/firebase-functions-test
> npm ERR!     dev firebase-functions-test@"^0.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> ```

Anyone know what's happening? I have tried this function on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages), but no luck at all. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` Please help me! I have been like this for two days!

[image: Images of functions]

[image: Images of functions]

Comment: Anyone ever experience this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're encountering is that `firebase-functions-test` specifies that it needs firebase-functions at at version `>=2.0.0`. npm interprets this as "*stable* versions greater than or equal to 2.0.0". That means versions like `3.24.1`, `3.0.0`, `2.3.1` would all be valid, but things like `4.0.0-rc.0` or a hypothetical `5.9.3-beta` would not.

When you ran `npm i firebase-functions@latest`, it grabbed the version that the devs had tagged as "latest", which was `4.0.0-rc-0`, which does not satisfy the aforementioned constraint.

I'd recommend explicitly installing a stable version (`npm install firebase-functions@3.24.1`), or -if you have access to `firebase-functions-test`- modify that package's `package.json` to specify `"firebase-functions": ">=2.0.0 || 4.0.0-rc.0"`.

Check out the [npm semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to see what specifiers match which versions.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't solve it either. I think I will rebuild this project from beginning. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If anyone wanna know what is going on, visit this link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5132

Answer (score 2):

Just use this

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save package-name
```