# Angular building locally, but not at Github. Getting npm ERR! - Oryx has failed to build the solution

Tags: angular, github

I have an Angular 12 application that is building just fine, with no errors or warning. I use Github to compile and upload it to Azure.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "My Application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.2.0",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^10.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.11.1",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.19",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "check-password-strength": "^2.0.7",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "material-icons": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^9.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.4.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.7",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "typicons.font": "^2.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic": "^28.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.2"
  }
}
```

As said, I can ng build just fine, but here is what I get at Git

```
Running 'npm install --unsafe-perm'...
57

58
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
59
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
60
npm ERR! 
61
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
62
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.5
63
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
64
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~12.1.1" from the root project
65
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"12.1.5" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.1.5
66
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
67
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.1.1" from the root project
68
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.4
69
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
70
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.1.1" from the root project
71
npm ERR!     1 more (@ngtools/webpack)
72
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
73
npm ERR! 
74
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
75
npm ERR! peer @angular/localize@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
76
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
77
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^10.0.0" from the root project
78
npm ERR! 
79
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@12.2.16
80
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
81
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.16" from @angular/localize@12.2.16
82
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
83
npm ERR!     peer @angular/localize@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
84
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
85
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^10.0.0" from the root project
86
npm ERR! 
87
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
88
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
89
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
90
npm ERR! 
91
```

Im runninng Node 16.14.1.

All this happened suddenly.

I've tried updating npm several times. I uninstalled and installed all npm's, I deleted package-lock and node_modules and reinstalled everything. Nothing worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your package-lock.json on github?

Comment: Hi Pieterjan. Yes, it is. I also deleted and regenerated the package-lock and I got the very same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a dependency conflict
try this

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

check this it could help you

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: Hello Ali. Ive tried that yesterday and it didnt work either.

Comment: Hey Danielle . check this and give me feedback .
https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-in-angular-while-installing-npm-packages/

Comment: That worked! Thanks Ali. Have a great Saturday.

Comment: A much better solution would be to fix the conflict. The new peer dependencies behaviour is there for a reason.