# dependency conflict when pushing to vercel

Tags: npm, vercel

greeting
i am having this problem when pushing to vercel
tried
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm audit fix --force`
localy but it didn't fix the issue
thanks for the help

```
user ctrl
```

code ERESOLVE13:34:04.676npm ERR!
ERESOLVE could not resolve13:34:04.677npm ERR!
13:34:04.677npm ERR! While resolving: react-animated-burgers@1.2.813:34:04.677npm ERR!
Found: react@17.0.213:34:04.677npm ERR!
node_modules/react13:34:04.678npm ERR!
peer react@"16.8.x" from react-konva@16.8.613:34:04.678npm ERR!
node_modules/react-konva13:34:04.678npm ERR!
peer react-konva@"^16.8.0  || ^17.0.0" from @react-spring/konva@9.4.313:34:04.679npm ERR!
node_modules/@react-spring/konva13:34:04.680npm ERR!
@react-spring/konva@"~9.4.3-beta.0" from react-spring@9.4.313:34:04.680npm ERR!
node_modules/react-spring13:34:04.680npm ERR!
react-spring@"^9.2.4" from the root project13:34:04.680npm ERR!
13:34:04.680npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:13:34:04.681npm ERR!
peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-animated-burgers@1.2.813:34:04.681npm ERR!
node_modules/react-animated-burgers13:34:04.681npm ERR!
react-animated-burgers@"^1.2.8" from the root project13:34:04.681npm ERR!
13:34:04.681npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.013:34:04.681npm ERR!
node_modules/react13:34:04.681npm ERR!
peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-animated-burgers@1.2.813:34:04.681npm ERR!
node_modules/react-animated-burgers13:34:04.682npm ERR!
react-animated-burgers@"^1.2.8" from the root project13:34:04.682npm ERR!
13:34:04.682npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry13:34:04.682npm ERR!
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps13:34:04.682npm ERR!
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.13:34:04.682npm ERR!
13:34:04.682npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

[image: err in vercel]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)