# Vercel Build deply error: npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree - While resolving: mocha-store@0.1.0

Tags: npm, vercel, sanity

`[20:19:35.061] Cloning github.com/oneboyfromife/macho-store (Branch: main, Commit: 48072bd)`
`[20:19:35.209] Previous build cache not available`
`[20:19:36.082] Cloning completed: 1.020s`
`[20:19:36.317] Running "vercel build"`
`[20:19:36.972] Vercel CLI 28.10.0`
`[20:19:37.389] Installing dependencies...`
`[20:19:39.176] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE`
`[20:19:39.179] npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`
`[20:19:39.180] npm ERR!` 
`[20:19:39.180] npm ERR! While resolving: mocha-store@0.1.0`
`[20:19:39.180] npm ERR! Found: @sanity/client@3.4.1`
`[20:19:39.180] npm ERR! node_modules/@sanity/client`
`[20:19:39.180] npm ERR!   @sanity/client@"^3.2.0" from the root project`
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR!` 
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:`
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR! peer @sanity/client@"^2.11.0" from next-sanity-image@3.2.1`
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR! node_modules/next-sanity-image`
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR!   next-sanity-image@"^3.2.1" from the root project`
`[20:19:39.181] npm ERR!` 
`[20:19:39.182] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry`
`[20:19:39.182] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`
`[20:19:39.182] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`
`[20:19:39.182] npm ERR!` 
`[20:19:39.182] npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.`
`[20:19:39.183]` 
`[20:19:39.183] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`[20:19:39.183] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T19_19_37_735Z-debug-0.log`
`[20:19:39.205] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1`

I was trying to deploy my nextjs website to vercel

Comment: Please edit your question to make it legible, it is difficult to understand and answer your question the way it is currently written.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 9):

By default Vercel will use `npm install` command to install required dependencies.
You can override that command with `npm install --force` or with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` command. You can do so from the Build & Development Settings section in Vercel dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

instead of

```
npm install
```

for install packages do this:

```
npm i package-name --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `install` command by going into the settings tab. Under Build & Development Settings, tick the Override button for Install Command and set it to `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`