# HTML Webpack Plugin installation

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-5

I'm trying to install HTML Webpack Plugin but I'm getting an error. The log file is this:

```
# npm resolution error report

While resolving: example-project@1.0.0
Found: webpack@4.46.0
node_modules/webpack
  webpack@"^4.35.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer webpack@"^5.20.0" from html-webpack-plugin@5.5.3
node_modules/html-webpack-plugin
  dev html-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I run `npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin` and I'm using Webpack 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)