# How can i fix multiple dependency errors

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, npm-install, npm-package, craco

When i am trying to install the npm packages using npm i command i get the following error[image: error]

my package.json

```
{
    "name": "workahub_redux",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@craco/craco": "6.4.5",
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.13.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
        "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
        "@jsonforms/core": "^3.0.0",
        "@jsonforms/material-renderers": "^3.0.0",
        "@jsonforms/react": "^3.0.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.9",
        "@mui/material": "^5.5.0",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.20",
        "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.8.1",
        "@sentry/react": "^7.25.0",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^7.25.0",
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.2.2",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.12.1",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@themesberg/tailwind-datepicker": "^1.1.0",
        "axios": "^1.3.3",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "google-map-react": "^2.2.0",
        "i18next": "^20.4.0",
        "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.20",
        "leaflet": "^1.8.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.21",
        "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
        "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
        "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dropzone": "^10.1.5",
        "react-easy-crop": "^4.6.3",
        "react-geocode": "^0.2.3",
        "react-highcharts": "^16.1.0",
        "react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
        "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
        "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
        "react-leaflet": "^4.0.0",
        "react-month-picker": "^2.2.1",
        "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.19",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "react-select": "^5.2.2",
        "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
        "react-sortablejs": "^6.1.4",
        "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
        "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2",
        "react-sweet-progress": "^1.1.2",
        "react-timezone-select": "^1.3.1",
        "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.3",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
        "tailwind-scrollbar": "^1.3.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "craco start",
        "build": "yarn build:css && craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "watch:css": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch postcss src/styles/tailwind.pcss -o src/styles/output.css --watch",
        "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.pcss -o src/styles/output.css --minify"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

1st i have updated "@craco/craco": "6.4.5" to "@craco/craco": "7.0.0" in package.json (as craco 6 supports react script 4 and i have react script 5 in package.json) but still got error i other dependancies

then i tried to use --legacy-peer-deps but then the react server fails to start

i have alo tried to update package.json file by using commands
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
but it does not updates all the packages some packages stays unupdated and the problem remains the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages