# I couldn't install showdown on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, showdown

```
$ npm install --save react-showdown

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-mde@11.5.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from react-split@2.0.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-split
npm ERR!     react-split@"^2.0.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, react-showdown)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-mde@11.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-mde
npm ERR!   react-mde@"^11.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-mde@11.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-mde
npm ERR!     react-mde@"^11.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/mofer/.npm/_logs/2023-09-11T11_22_26_434Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/mofer/.npm/_logs/2023-09-11T11_22_26_434Z-debug-0.log
```

i tried npm install showdown and the above one but I just couldn't resolve it

Comment: I just didn't want to use the --force flag

Comment: You need to use `force` or `legact-peer-deps` flag because `react-mde@11.5.0` only support `react@17.x.x`

Comment: I mean `legacy-peer-deps` typo.

Comment: Did you try this `npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save react-showdown` ? some related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)