# how use or install Radium in reactjs 18

Tags: reactjs, radium

when i install the Radium dependency in my project i have many errors like this:

```
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from radium@0.26.2
npm ERR! node_modules/radium
npm ERR!   radium@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\nariman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-18T07_10_59_624Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

my react version is 18

Comment: Check this answer for complete information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862745/6025073

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it can't be installed on version 18, downgrade your React app to version 17 using the following command

npm install react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2