# How do I read npm "conflicting peer dependency" error messages?

Tags: npm

I'm in the process of trying to upgrade some npm dependencies of a project I own, and I'm getting a "conflicting peer dependency" error.

I see a lot of questions on this site asking for help fixing such errors. However, I've struggled to find information on what these errors actually *mean*. I feel like if I understood that, I'd have a chance of figuring out how to solve the problem on my own.

Here's the error message I'm trying to interpret:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/localize@11.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This can be reproduced by running `npm install` in the root of [this Github branch](https://github.com/google/peoplemath/tree/ngconflict) (I'm using npm `7.10.0`.)

My general understanding of a "conflicting peer dependency" error is that some package I depend upon is expressing a [peer dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) on a package version spec which does not match the version of that package that I actually have installed.

For example, if my project has direct dependencies on packages `A` and `B`, and I have version `12.0.0` of `A` installed but my version of `B` has a peer dependency on `^11.0.0` of package `A`, then I will get a conflicting peer dependency error, because I'm using `B` with a version of `A` that it is potentially incompatible with.

Therefore, my best guess as to what this error message could mean is that some package I depend upon has a peer dependency on `@angular/localize` version spec `^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next`, but this spec does not match the version of `@angular/localize` I have installed.

When I look at [my package-lock.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/peoplemath/ngconflict/package-lock.json), I do see that the `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular` entry has an entry `"@angular/localize": "^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next"` in its `peerDependencies`.

However, this is the only mention of `@angular/localize` anywhere in this file -- or indeed in [package.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/peoplemath/ngconflict/package.json). I haven't explicitly requested for it to be installed. Furthermore, it is marked as `"optional": true` in the `peerDependenciesMeta` of `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular`. So it's surprising to see an error message related to it.

The error mentions that the specific conflicting peer dependency is `@angular/localize@11.2.10`. I don't see where that version number is coming from. But regardless,  it actually seems to match the dependency specification underneath: if I go to [semver.npmjs.com](https://semver.npmjs.com/) and type in `@angular/localize` as the package and `^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next` as the version range, I see version `11.2.10` of the package highlighted in green, indicating that it matches the range.

So I'd really appreciate some help understanding in detail what this error message is telling me. I don't know why `npm` is trying to install `11.2.10` of `@angular/localize`, or why it thinks this conflicts with the peer dependency specification of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. It feels like I might be misunderstanding this message completely.

I'm guessing this boils down to some kind of incompatibility between the latest published versions of some of the Angular packages. If anyone has any pointers on how this particular error should be fixed, that would be great -- but I'm much more interested in simply understanding what the error message is telling me, so I can work it out for myself.

Comment: @GHULAMNABI Thanks! It sounds like ChatGPT has no idea how to make sense of these messages either, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reading through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20208), it appears my interpretation of the error message was correct, and that this is in fact a bug in `npm`.

This appears to have been reported as [npm/cli/issues/3083](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3083); a fix [has been merged](https://github.com/npm/arborist/pull/266), so I guess we just have to wait until it gets included in some upcoming `npm` release.

Comment: [Still not fixed](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3666)

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: still not fixed

Comment: still not fixed :(

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answer's the OP's question.  Weren't they asking about how to read the actual output?

Comment: @mattforsythe he is the OP

Comment: Checking in... Tried updating an old project via npm and seems to not be fixed... o.o

Answer (score 37):

**Recommendation:**

Check out [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn).

I was able to circumvent the issue in NPM by using [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn) instead of NPM. Yarn is basically a wrapper utility around NPM that adds extra features, which are super useful. It's especially helpful for managing NPM dependencies better.

For instance, it can check if a package is already installed on your machine for another project, directly or as a sub dependency, and can reuse that installed version rather than re-installing a copy of the same package; saves space and makes for faster installations, especially with some of the most common dependencies.

So, due to the optimized way Yarn handles dependencies, I think it helps avoid this issue faced by the OP.

**Resolution:**

1. First, delete the `node_modules` folder in your project.
2. Yarn will complain about any `package-lock.json` files, so delete that too (or back it up, then delete it). Do not delete `package.json`, yarn will need that.
3. Simply install yarn: `npm i yarn` (you could do this globally, too).
4. Then run `yarn install` in your project directory.

**Alternative:**

Promoting a solution suggested by @IvanRubinson in the comments:

> The problem with deleting `package-lock.json` is that you lose the version pinning, so when you run yarn it will upgrade all dependencies, which can break stuff and cause dependency hell. Consider `yarn import` instead.

Comment: The problem with deleting `package-lock.json` is that you lose the version pinning, so when you run `yarn` it will upgrade all dependencies, which can break stuff and cause dependency hell. Consider `yarn import` instead

Comment: I get same peer dependency errors when I try to run `npm i yarn`. So, I installed yarn globally and then when I try `yarn install`, I get `error Couldn't find package "tslib" on the "npm" registry.`

Comment: @Kashyap that error looks like something specific to a dependency you have unique to your situation, not necessarily something with yarn itself.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Good point; I've added your suggestion as an alternative approach for anyone who cannot simply delete `package-lock.json`. Thanks!

Comment: "If anyone has any pointers on how this particular error should be fixed, that would be great -- but I'm much more interested in simply understanding what the error message is telling me, so I can work it out for myself." - I came to this question because I had the same error myself, and I felt that like many others they may be looking for a solution. I don't see how your comment is at all useful or constructive. Besides that, the OP answered his own question over a year before my post.

Answer (score 0):

For some legendary package (or the packages that has not updated for a few years) that specify a peer dependency which is in conflict with a package you want to install, you can try to deleted the peer dependency in the old package.

This happened to me when I tried to install a package that requires higher version of react. But a legendary package (in my case, react-wavy-audio which has not been updated for 3 years) specified a peer dependency for react of 16.0, while new package requires react >= 17.0. Because of this conflict, I was not able to install the new package. *I edited package-lock.json where it has an entry for the peer dependency for the legendary package, you can try to either delete it or choose a compatible version*.

**Warning**: Would like to point out that this is a hacky solution and not recommended for everyone. There is also a chance the newer dependency would make the legendary package not to perform. When you reinstall all packages or deleted package-lock.json, you would need to redo the steps.  However, it worked for my case.

Comment: I am sure you mean legacy, not "legendary" :P

Comment: "Legacy" it is. Or both, ... :-)

Answer (score -1):

In contrast, I had to download the most recent version of Node because of the issues I was experiencing.
It is possible that the current version of Node is incompatible with your ongoing project.
Install the previous version of Node again