# @angular-devkit/build-angular dependency issue while upgrading from Angular 11.0.5 to 12.2.16

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am try to upgrade an Angular project from Angular v11 using `ng update` and got peer dependency error. I referred [How do I read npm "conflicting peer dependency" error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185714/how-do-i-read-npm-conflicting-peer-dependency-error-messages) to understand about the peer dependency errors, but it still does not help in this case.

. Here's the output of `ng update`:

```
We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

  Name                               Version                  Command to update
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cli                       11.2.18 -> 12.2.9        ng update @angular/cli@12
  @angular/core                      11.2.14 -> 12.2.9        ng update @angular/core@12
There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
You can update the additional packages by running the update command of your package manager.
```

Upon running `ng update @angular/cli@12` I get the below error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.16
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Here's my package.json
Before running `ng update`

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

After running `ng update`

```
    {
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I checked the code https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/12.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/package.json

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
```

As far as I know, ^12.0.0 should not cause a problem with 12.2.16 as it is in the same major version, so why am I still getting peer dependency error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is happening because of a Semver bug in npm. You should be able to fix it by adding `--force` to your upgrade command or use yarn instead.

ref. GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21204#issuecomment-868518668)

(I too had the exact issue, this worked fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

you should better update properly the packages corresponding to your version by checking compatibility
here : https://www.npmjs.com/
and here: https://www.npmpeer.dev/packages/@angular-devkit/build-angular/compatibility

You should also try to use this command in your terminal : `npm list package 'packageName'` to get the dependency tree.

All this requires patience and not brute force.
You should properly resolved theses conflict and not use `--force` or you'll run into an infinite loop of issues. I've been there trust me.

Good Luck for the next ones !