# Error when running 'npm install' and 'npm start'

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I ran `npm install`  in my project directory.

But I get this error while running `npm install`:

````
D:\Personal\██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████\rn-starter-main>npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\███████\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\███████\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-02T02_39_48_352Z-debug-0.log```
````

`npm install --force` installed the packages, but when I run `npm start`, I get the following error:

```
D:\Personal\████████████████████████████████████████████████████████\rn-starter-main>npm start

> start
> expo start

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                         │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (5.3.0).                 │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 5.1.1                                │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Starting project at D:\Personal\███████████████████████████████████\rn-starter-main
Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?
```

For the conflicting peer dependency error, I tried:

1. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`  and
2. `npm install --force`

But none of them seems to have worked. This error is still persisting.

For the expo not found error, I tried commands like:

1. `npm cache clean`,
2. `expo install`,
3. `expo update`,
4. `npm add expo`
5. `expo rebuild` etc.

I thought this error might be due to older expo versions like 36 and 37 that I've worked with, so, I uninstalled all of Node and NPM and downloaded them again from https://nodejs.org/en/ , but I still get the same "conflicting peer dependency" and "Unable to find expo" errors. Could you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185714/how-do-i-read-npm-conflicting-peer-dependency-error-messages                      This is an similar question is says it's a bug as according git bug report I think that's the case

Comment: So it is not fixed yet? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `npm install -g expo-cli` fixes both the errors. These errors are just due to npm not being installed globally.