# Unable run npm install command in angular 15

Tags: angular, npm-install

I have a project which is build on angular with  **15.2.4** and Nodejs version is **18.12.1**.

Whenever I tried to run the command `npm install` I am getting error [image: error]

Can someone please help me to solve these peer dependencies.

Comment: Some guy asked the same question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185714/how-do-i-read-npm-conflicting-peer-dependency-error-messages)

Answer (score 0):

try this `npm i --legacy-per-deps`

you have old dependencies, so you need to update them.