downgrade @angular/google-maps version
I need to downgrade the @angular/google-maps version of my project, which is in it's 15.0.2 version, but the Angular version I'm working with is 14.2.6, so when i try to install another library it creates a conflict. I need to downgrade the @angular/google-maps version.
i tried to uninstall @angular/google-maps so i could install an older version, it throwed a conflict with tslib. If someone could help me or give me advice I would appreciate very much, thanks
PS C:\Project> npm uninstall @angular/google-maps@15.2.9
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/google-maps@15.2.9
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.2.7" from @angular/material@14.2.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       peer @angular/material@"14.2.7" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@14.2.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!         @angular/material-moment-adapter@"^14.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"^7.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!   @angular/google-maps@"^15.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@15.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!     @angular/google-maps@"^15.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Marti\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-22T19_10_48_543Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Marti\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-22T19_10_48_543Z-debug-0.log


Were you using git in your project? If so, have you tried reverting your project before you installed the google maps library?

You can also try out Yarn as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161619/18422887

Just use --force option after the package name so it would uninstall desired version
