# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined postcss/cssloader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
./src/components/banners/banner.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/components/banners/banner.css)
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined

I have this popping up and I've tried different answers for similar issues but I'm not able to get this resolved. I've tried updating my packages and even went as far as deleting `node_modules` folder and re-installing it and it still gives me this error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: a related error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556739/application-doesnt-run-after-updating-postcss-to-version-8-react/67880388#67880388