# How to pass SASS option to Angular library builder

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have an Angular 11 library using Bootstrap 4.5
ng-packagr uses SASS 1.34 which yields a lot of warning about the deprecation of the division operator, which is used a lot in Bootstrap (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div)

The warning in question:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

There is an option : `--quiet-deps` that can be used when manually executing sass, to hide these warnings.

My question is, how and where to pass this option when building the Angular library ?
It didn't find any possible configuration for the `ng build` command or in the `ng-package.json` file

Comment: Please include an example of the warning in your post for searchability purposes. Is this [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34051)? Seems sass don't like supporting suppression of warnings [github comment](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2822#issuecomment-482914373) and bootstrap may fix this pretty [soon](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34051#issuecomment-853613435) so the solution may end up being update to v5.1.0 when this comes along

Comment: Edited to add the warning. I know Bootstrap 5 will fix the issue, but it is not a solution, a lot of plugins are not yet compatible with v5.
As I said there are options to mute sass (quietDeps and quiet) I just don't know how to pass them trough the Angular build chain.

Comment: The Node API of Dart SASS does not expose the quietDeps options at all.... https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3065

Comment: Doesn't directly solves your issue, but this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956076/2445933

Comment: @AndrewShustariov thanks, using yarn this works natively `"resolutions": { "**/ng-packagr/sass": "~1.32.13" }`

Answer (score 3):

As far as the CLI release notes for [12.1.2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v12.1.2) go this feature was added as a fix for [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21235) issue. By simply omitting `--verbose` from your build command should result in no warnings.

(Run `npm list -g @angular/cli` and `npm list @angular-devkit/build-angular` to see the versions you are using.)