# Problem with Node-sass in legacy project with Ember

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, node-sass

I have a legacy project in `ember` and when trying to run `npm i` it **gives the following errors:**

```
> node-sass@3.13.1 install 
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-72_bind
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-72_binding.nod

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.z
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting zip contents
Removing phantomjs-prebuilt\li
Copying extracted folder AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip-exhantomjs-2.1.1-windows -> node_modules\phanantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at node_moilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall node_modules\bdules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standa

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall node_modules\bdules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall node_modules\bules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall node_modules
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe \\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_libr
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\node_modules\\node-gygyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFroich\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesgyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFroich\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesgyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\RedeCo_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nhich.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nndex.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nindows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFroich\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesgyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFroich\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modu:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesgyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\RedeCo_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nhich.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nndex.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\nindows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location 
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFrode-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFrone-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulels.js:299:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\RededorFrontEnd\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libslags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN babel-plugin-debug-macros@0.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-beta.42 but none is ind. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
PS C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\> npm install node-sass

> node-sass@6.0.1 install C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\node
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v6.0.1/win32-x64-72_bindie
Download complete .] - :
Binary saved to C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\node-sass\vend32-x64-72\binding.node
Caching binary to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\6.0.1\win32-x64-72_binding.nod

> node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\ass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\node-sass\vend32-x64-72\binding.node
Testing binary
PS C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\> npm i

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\brosass-source-maps\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-72_bindde
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-72_binding.nod

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_mophantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.z
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting zip contents
Removing C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\litom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip-ex1627499579693\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows -> C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\noules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_mophantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\bolyfill\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standarary!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\begister\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\buntime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\odules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_exibsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\node_modules\\broccol-source-maps\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',      
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',     
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='      
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\RedeCorFrontEnd\\node_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduoccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modulesoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_modules\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\RedeCorFrontEnd\\node_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\_modules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\broccoli-sass-source-maps\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\\\Documents\\PROJETOS\\\\ndules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location 
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\RedeCotizadorFronode_modules\broccoli-sass-source-maps\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\\Documents\PROJETOS\\node_moduleeful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN babel-plugin-debug-macros@0.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-beta.42 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.   

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-28T19_13_06_459Z-debug.log
```

But I've already tried everything below:

1. Remove Node-Modules
2. Delete Package-lock.json
3. Install the latest node-sass version
4. Install the latest version of gulp

But even so the same mistake perpetuates, I believe `ember-cli` is doing this.

How should I proceed to fix this problem? I use **Windows** and on an **Intranet** (Company).

**My Versions:**

```
node: v12.14.1
npm 6.13.4
```

**PACKAGE.JSON:**

```
{
  "name": "xp-investimentos-frontend",
  "version": "0.3.1",
  "description": "Small description for xp-investimentos-frontend goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
    "ember-accordion": "0.3.6",
    "ember-ajax": "2.4.1",
    "ember-array-contains-helper": "1.3.2",
    "ember-bootstrap": "0.7.1",
    "ember-browserify": "1.1.9",
    "ember-charts": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "2.5.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-array-slice": "2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "5.2.1",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker": "0.5.5",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy": "0.5.3",
    "ember-cli-clipboard": "0.8.1",
    "ember-cli-d3-shape": "0.8.5",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-inline-content": "^0.4.1",
    "ember-cli-mirage": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-nouislider": "0.9.0",
    "ember-cli-pagination": "3.1.4",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.3.1",
    "ember-cli-selectize": "0.5.5",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-concurrency": "0.7.4",
    "ember-data": "^2.5.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-file-upload": "2.5.0",
    "ember-inflector": "2.1.0",
    "ember-inline-svg": "^0.1.7",
    "ember-inputmask": "0.2.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-maskmoney": "0.4.3",
    "ember-modal-dialog": "^2.4.4",
    "ember-models-table": "1.7.0",
    "ember-moment": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7",
    "ember-resize": "0.0.12",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "2.0.1",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.3.0",
    "ember-uploader": "1.2.2",
    "hashcode": "^1.0.3",
    "ivy-tabs": "2.0.0",
    "jquery-maskmoney": "3.0.2",
    "liquid-fire": "0.27.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "closest-num": "0.0.1",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.4.2",
    "ember-cli-data-export": "^0.1.29",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "ocanvas": "^2.9.1",
    "percent-value": "^1.0.7",
    "socket.io": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because there's no uploaded binary of that [`node-sass` version](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1) for node 12.x. It only goes up to node 7. It then tries compiling it for that node version but you do not have installed `python2` (and you would also need visual C++, unsure how does this work on windows).

`node-sass` 6.0 is not the problem here and it's not your module that's problematic. A dependency of some other module requires that version of `node-sass`. So you'll need to override the dependency somehow. [Like doing this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524488/1549541) You'll need to update that for every ocurrence of every node-sass `3.13.1` version.

Another alternative is to build the module against that version of node, but you'll need to install visual c++ and `python2`. [I found some further steps here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows).

> Install the current version of Python from the [Microsoft Store
> package](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-microsoft-store-package).
>
> Install tools and configuration manually:
>
> - Install Visual C++ Build Environment: [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools) (using
>   "Visual C++ build tools" workload) or [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community) (using
>   the "Desktop development with C++" workload)
> - Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2017`

And the last alternative would be to simply install a [node 7 version](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.7.3/node-v7.7.3-x64.msi).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell. My guess is this error is related to your network infrastructure. But you may have other issues after workaround this one. Try running your project behind a "owned" infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is

1. download binary version node "win32-x64-72_binding.node" from below
   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1 (from v4.12+ available to download).
2. add it to below folder. ( If folders doesn't exist after npm-cache, just create it.)
   C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\3.13.1\win32-x64-72_binding.node

Now, try to do "npm install" -> it will work.

check the comments here as well.
https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sass/pull/74