# npm install is failing because of node-sass issue

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-gyp, node-sass

[image]
[image]

```
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.18.9 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.3.2 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-side-effect@1.2.0 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/snema4/.npm/_logs/2022-10-31T10_25_11_582Z-debug.log
```

I tried removing package.lock file and node-modules folder. Tried uninstalling node-sass but still getting the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

please check node version of yours.
Node 14 doesn't support node-sass 5.0 version.

check below table from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
NodeJS -- Supported node-sass version
Node15 --   5.0+, <7.0
Node14 -- 4.14+

check below comments as well:
https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-sass/pull/74#pullrequestreview-927390989
[Problem with Node-sass in legacy project with Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568019/problem-with-node-sass-in-legacy-project-with-ember/71691830#71691830)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

`node-sass` has been deprecated. So you should replace it with the package `sass`.

You can do this as follows

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Everything will work same