# How do I stop the prettier dependency in node_modules overriding the project .prettierrc?

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte, prettier

In the `node_modules` folder there is a `prettier` install (package.json says `"version": "1.19.1",`) that is overriding the .prettierrc in my project root.

When I delete that dir, formatting returns to normal.

But this is only temporary as `npm i` puts it back. Something has it as a dependency, even tho searching for `"prettier"` or `1.19.1` only returns the `package-lock.json`.

I have other projects that work correctly without a node_modules installation of prettier, but this github template had it.

How can I clear this up? Ideally, I want to only use the project level `.prettierrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which package is the culprit by searching in your `package-lock.json`. Each package in there has a `requires` field which lists its dependencies. That way you can traverse the chain to find out which dependency is causing the install.

Once you found the package, you have several options to force a specific dependency. In your case, you would force the latest version of `prettier-plugin-svelte` to be installed. In your case it's probably best to use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). You first add the latest version of `prettier-plugin-svelte` to your `package.json`, then do `npm i`, then make sure that only the latest `prettier-plugin-svelte` appears in your `node_modules`, then run `npm shrinkwrap`. More info here: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/

More info and alternatives on forcing versions for various tools (npm/yarn) can be found in this StackOverflow answer: [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)