# Uniswap v3 Deploy Hardhat Plugin fails - uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin

Tags: npx, hardhat, uniswap

I have followed along with the deployment steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ7QMmm7hJc for the Hardhat-based Uniswap v3 dev setup.

https://github.com/Uniswap/hardhat-plugin-deploy-v3

In creating a new project:

```
npm init
npm add --save-dev hardhat
npx hardhat - select create an empty config file
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers

// add: require("uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin"); to hardhat.config.js
// add: require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"); to hardhat.config.js
```

The first issue I encountered was that I had to downgrade Node to v16.3.1.

`npx hardhat` - i see "deploy-uniswap in the AVAILABLE TASKS

[image]

`npx hardhat deploy-uniswap` results in a nasty error full of bytecode and some additional details:

[image]

```
...3000706000a", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:225:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:237:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:241:21)
    at new ContractFactory (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1162:20)
    at UniswapV3Deployer.deployContract (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin\src\deployer\UniswapV3Deployer.ts:139:21)
    at UniswapV3Deployer.deployPositionDescriptor (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin\src\deployer\UniswapV3Deployer.ts:112:24)
    at Function.deploy (C:\DEV\uniswap-example2\node_modules\uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin\src\deployer\UniswapV3Deployer.ts:27:47)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9) {
  reason: 'invalid bytecode',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'bytecode',
  value: '0x60c06040523480156100105760008...
```

I can't seem to find any other info on this.

Comment: ElHaix did you resolve your case ?

Comment: Not yet.  I tabled this and branched onto a related dev path.

Answer (score 1):

There is some breaking change in `uniswap/v3-periphery` and I solved it by overriding a dependency in the `package.json`:

```json
"overrides": {
  "@uniswap/v3-periphery": "1.0.1"
}
```

Details about overriding are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@openzeppelin/contracts": "4.4.2",
  "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "4.4.2",
  "@uniswap/v3-core": "1.0.0",
  "@uniswap/v3-periphery": "1.0.1",
  "bignumber.js": "9.0.2",
  "dotenv": "11.0.0",
  "uniswap-v3-deploy-plugin": "0.1.0"
}
```