# React Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting issues with iframe.
Till today everything was working as expected. Today I added a very simple Modal component and somehow iframe started appearing. It appears when I am editing the file and hot reload is done. Also with this issue, it's showing an error in Console as "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined".
Can someone please help me with this?

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Close from "../static/assets/close-white.svg"

const trapStyles = {
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: 0
}
const Test = () => {

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div data-react-modal-body-trap="" tabIndex="0" style={trapStyles}/>,
        document.getElementById("app")
    )
}

const Modal = ({ open, onClose, children }) => {

    useEffect(() => {

        if (open)document.getElementById("app").classList.add("ReactModal__Body--open");

        return () => {
            document.getElementById("app").classList.remove("ReactModal__Body--open")
        }
    })
    if (!open) return null

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <>
            <Test />
            <div className="ReactModal__Overlay--after-open">
                <div className="modal-form-page"
                     tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
                    <button onClick={onClose} className="close-modal">
                        <img id="close-button" alt="close" src={Close}/>
                    </button>
                    { children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>,
        document.getElementById("ModalPortal")
    )
};

export default Modal;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/>
    <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
    <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body id="app">
<noscript>You need to enable javascript to run this website</noscript>
<div id="content">
<-- All other content render here -->
</div>
<div class="ReactModalPortal" id="ModalPortal"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (index.js:1)
4043 @ VM128:2
r @ VM128:2
8048 @ VM128:2
r @ VM128:2
8641 @ VM128:2
r @ VM128:2
(anonymous) @ VM128:2
(anonymous) @ VM128:2
(anonymous) @ VM128:2
e.onload @ index.js:1
be @ index.js:1
he @ index.js:1
tryDismissErrorOverlay @ webpackHotDevClient.js:184
onHotUpdateSuccess @ webpackHotDevClient.js:109
handleApplyUpdates @ webpackHotDevClient.js:257
(anonymous) @ webpackHotDevClient.js:273
load (async)
be @ index.js:1
he @ index.js:1
tryDismissErrorOverlay @ webpackHotDevClient.js:184
onHotUpdateSuccess @ webpackHotDevClient.js:109
handleApplyUpdates @ webpackHotDevClient.js:257
(anonymous) @ webpackHotDevClient.js:273
Promise.then (async)
tryApplyUpdates @ webpackHotDevClient.js:271
handleSuccess @ webpackHotDevClient.js:106
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:203
```

Comment: /**
 * until https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11771
 * gets fixed, let's hide the problem and not address it
 */
body > iframe[style*="2147483647"]:not([id="webpack-dev-server-client-overlay"]) {
    display: none;
} add this to the root css file. will fix the bug temporarily until there is a proper fix . Credits : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11771#issuecomment-1017125835

Comment: Could you include the contents of your `package.json` in the question? Please.

Comment: This solved it for me `let process = {}` adding that to one of my root files.

Answer (score 241):

Upgrading to react-scripts v5 is not always the solution.

The full reason for this bug is described [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773). In short here is a *brief* summary:

The error is as a result of `react-error-overlay` (*which many people would never have heard of because it is a dependency of `react-scripts`*). This package's dependencies were update to support `webpack` v5, which unfortunately is not compatible with `react-scripts` v4.

---

### Method 1 (Override a package version)

If upgrading to `react-scripts` v5 is not working for you, you can also try another workaround which is to pin `react-error-overlay` to version `6.0.9`:

Delete your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`, then install your dependencies again.

##### Using yarn

*yarn will take the resolutions field into consideration out of the box.*

```
"resolutions": {
  "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
}
```

For **yarn workspaces**, place the above resolution in the root `package.json`, not in the problematic folder. See this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773#issuecomment-1029162472) comment.

##### Using npm ([>=v8.3.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.0))

The equivalent of `resolutions` for npm is `overrides`.

```
"overrides": {
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
```

##### Using npm (<8.3.0)

You need to make sure `npm` uses the `resolutions` field when you run `npm install`. To automate the installation, *see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791920/2089675)*

---

### Method 2 (Use a webpack plugin)

Yet another (not so popular) workaround is to use a webpack plugin:

```
plugins:[
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      process: {env: {}}
  })
]
```

If you use [`craco`](https://github.com/dilanx/craco) (v6.3.0+), you just need to modify your `craco.config.js` file to add that plugin:

```
{
  ...
  webpack: {
    plugins: {
      add: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          process: {env: {}}
        })
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) users, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151846/2089675) or this [github comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773#issuecomment-1042528090).

This last method is not popular because not many CRA users ever have to touch webpack directly to work with react.

Comment: In the craco case, should I just use `webpack.DefinePlugin` with argument `{process: {env: {}}}` ? Or do I reference the dependency version there somehow?

Comment: @xtra if you just want to do it through craco, then using the `webpack.DefinePlugin` plugin with those arguments should be enough. I've updated the answer to make it explicit that there are two methods for solving the problem

Comment: The method 1, fixed (patched more accurated) the issue... that's annoying...

Comment: Method 1 example works only for yarn. For NPM uses:
"overrides": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },

Comment: I still get the error (as per the question Title), but I am using "react-scripts": "3.4.4", and packages-lock.json show "webpack": "4.42.0"; Somehow this error has not occurred before in my React work.

Comment: Installing `react-error-overlay@6.0.9` no longer freezes the screen for me, but hot reload doesn't happen at all any more.

Comment: Method 2, with craco 6.1.1 does not work for me.

Comment: @MathieuCAROFF You need to upgrade your craco version. The latest version that supports the method I've shown, is [v6.3.0](https://github.com/dilanx/craco/releases/tag/v6.3.0)

Comment: Method 1 worked for me. Using react-app-rewired(v2.2.1) and  npm (v8.5.0)

Comment: Method 2(using craco) worked for me but had to updated related packages to their latest version

Comment: Method 1, Using npm (>=v8.3.0) worked for me when I also installed the specific version: 
`npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9`

Answer (score 137):

I tried updating **react-scripts to 5.0.0, but that didn't work.**

### Solution: -

- If you are using `npm`: -

`npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9`

- If you are using `yarn`: -

`yarn add -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9`

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773

Comment: or yarn add -dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9, and copy the react-error-overlay in node_modules to node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules

Comment: This worked for in `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"

Comment: I tried this suggestion and got `Line 0:  Parsing error: ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6 and in the module context`.

Comment: Updating react-scripts is not always the least painful solution, some apps are still relying on webpack v4 polyfills. This is a life safer. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

Add this code in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"  
}
```

After that run `npm install` command.
It worked for me after 2 days of scrolling on the internet.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

Until a fix is final([maybe this PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11799)), for anyone using npm(not yarn) the solution is this:

add to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},

"scripts":{
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    ....
},

"devDependencies":{
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
...
}
```

and then do an

`npm install`

Comment: Also needed "react-scripts": "4.0.1" version in the dependencies.

Comment: this worked for me! however, if using yarn, you don't need the preinstall script

Comment: this worked for me as well when you have node 14 this is the solution because if you don't do this it will install "react-error-overlay": "6.0.11", by default with react-scripts 4.0.0

Answer (score 26):

If you have created your react app using **Vite** then prefix your environment variables with VITE_ in .env file.

> `VITE_API_URL=http://localhost:5000`

you can access it using:

```
import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
```

Here is an example of how to use the environment variable in your code:

```js
const createDeck = async (title) => {
  const response = await request.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/deck`, {title});
  return response.data;
}
```

To know more visit - https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: Superb, it's my first time using Vite and this error disturbed me. I did something like: ```const  API_BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_URL;```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. worked for me as i created react app using Vite.

Answer (score 18):

The issue was solved by updating react-scripts to 5.0.0

Comment: I upgraded my react-scripts to 5.0.0, but still facing this error, and also it freezes UI

Comment: it freezes the UI because you have an error.

Comment: My setup is ejected and I don't have react-scripts, what do?

Answer (score 16):

I found the best solution.

The problem is because you lose `window.process` variable when React hotloads, and process exists only on node, not the browser.

So you should inject it to browser when the app loads.

Add this line to `App.js`

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.process = {
      ...window.process,
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: In case you need this in class form, then use componentDidMount (){ window.process = { ...window.process } }

Comment: For me it was redux middleware code inside the store that was looking for process, so had to add `window.process = { ...window.process }` inside my store.js file above the middleware code, but otherwise seems to be a good workaround without messing with deps.

Comment: This causes me to have te next error:
**TypeError: process.nextTick is not a function**

Comment: In 2023 this is the only answer that worked for me with create-react-app. Note: I tried literally all the others that don't require interaction with webpack or ejecting. This is a deal-breaking for CRA and moi

Comment: What about this? `let process = {}` just added that to my index.js and it solved the issue!

Answer (score 12):

A lot of answers suggest overriding the `react-error-overlay` to `6.0.9`, but this didn't work for me (on February 11th, 2022). I was using `react-scripts 5.0.0` and `react-error-overlay 6.0.10` before trying out the overlay override.

Instead of going through the hastle of defining the webpack configuration in my CRA application (as [suggested by smac89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368760/react-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined/71083312#answer-70452191)), I downgraded `react-scripts` to `4.0.3`.

It works fine with `react-scripts: 4.0.3`, which resolved `react-error-overlay` to `6.0.10`.

So, my fix is:

- Set `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"` in package.json
- Delete your lock file (yarn.lock or package-lock.json) and node_modules
- Run install

Comment: ONLY ONE working for me, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12354

Answer (score 12):

For those still having issues with this: If using Webpack, run `npm install -D dotenv-webpack` and if using typescript `npm install -D @types/dotenv-webpack`.
Then in your Webpack config, add `import Dotenv from "dotenv-webpack";`
And

```
...
plugins: [
    ...
    new Dotenv(),
],
...
```

See https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/blob/master/README.md

After trying everything else, this finally worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. That was the only solution that really worked.

Comment: So I had to use this after `new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified)` in the new `react-scripts` version `5.0.1`. Using it by itself didn't work. You will get a  `Conflicting values for 'process.env'`. Yet the project runs. My main concern is the build output now at this point. Thank you for this. I know Next.js uses this so good suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

The only solution that worked for me was a modification of what @smac89 wrote for craco.
First add process as a dependency.

```
yarn add process or npm i process
```

Then add these lines to your craco.config.js.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
webpack: {
     ...
     plugins: {
        add: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser.js',
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            }),
        ],
      },
    },
};
```

This, in turn, **doesn't** show the below warning in the console every time you start the project.

> WARNING in DefinePlugin Conflicting values for 'process.env'

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading from react-scripts 4.0.3 to 5.0.0 Did not work for me.
The only thing that finally worked is the above proposed solution

using yarn

```
  "devDependencies": {
        "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
      },
  "resolutions": {
        "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
      }
```

then yarn install

for npm i think "resolutions" has to be replaced by "overrides"

Comment: Just adding the resolutions worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using npm > v8.3 you can use `overrides` like so in your `package.json`.

```
  "overrides": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
```

For more information about overrides, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions).

The issue is a breaking change in `6.0.10`, some dependencies like `react-dev-utils` will install this version even if you pin the version of `react-error-overlay` to `6.0.9` that is why it is necessary to use overrides.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Vite+React. Please check this page:
[1]: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

The .env variable need to be named with the prefix **VITE_APP_(VARIABLE NAME)**
Then if you are getting the error: **"process is not defined"**, replace **process** with **import.meta.env**

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

***Only for Vite users:***

Vite reveals the env variable on the particular type of object called `import.meta.env` and provides some built-in variables in some cases:

- `import.meta.env.MODE`: The *mode* the app is running in(type *string*)
- `import.meta.env.BASE_URL`: the *base url* the app is being served from(type *string*)
- `import.meta.env.PROD`: whether the app is running in production mode(type *boolean*)
- `import.meta.env.DEV`: whether the app is running in development mode(type *boolean*)
- `import.meta.env.SSR`: whether the app is running in server(type *boolean*)

Vite uses *dotenv* to load additional environment variables from the following files in your environment directory: like, `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.[mode]` and `.env.[mode].local`.

> Note: An env file for a specific mode (*e.g. .env.production*) will
> take higher priority than a generic one (*e.g. .env*).
> env files are loaded at the start of Vite. Restart the server after making changes.

Only `VITE_SOME_KEY` will be exposed as `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` to your client source code, but `SOME_KEY` will not. Simply use in Vite,
`import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` to get values, Otherwise it gets **undefined**. Also, Vite uses **dotenv-expand** to expand variables out of the box.

To know more, you can check this doc - https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Answer (score 3):

Start every property key name with: **REACT_APP_**

**Example: REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:9000/**

***If you are using Vite:***

Go to: **vite.config.js**

```
import {
  defineConfig
} from 'vite'
```

**Add**

```
define: {
    'process.env': {}
  }
```

in the defineConfig

**Example:**

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For people running into this issue:
Apparently `process?.env?.ENV_VAR` and `process.env.ENV_VAR` are not the same.

I haven't figured out why exactly, but having the conditional accessor gives this error, even after applying the overrides/resolutions fix.
But part of it is how it is transpiled to the final js, without the conditional operators the process.env part is dropped.

(I would put this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from react-scripts 4.0.3 to 5.0.0 worked for me.

I ended up with the following error (relevant if you're using craco):

*TypeError: match.loader.options.plugins is not a function*

This was solved by @weiwei [in their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70409552/9944706)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this works for me, as Kaleb was saying

> if using Webpack, run npm install -D dotenv-webpack and if using
> typescript npm install -D @types/dotenv-webpack.
> Then in your Webpack config, add import Dotenv from "dotenv-webpack";
> And

```
plugins: [
    ...
    new Dotenv(),
],
```

Comment: Please add some description and complete code for the common users to understand the solution

Answer (score 1):

i just updated version of react-script now it works fine for me

```
  "dependencies": {    
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The error may be misleading when using React 18.

In my case, I was getting the error `process is not defined`, because the variable `process.env.API_URL` was not defined. However, the same error was not thrown for `process.env.NODE_ENV` or `process.env.API_HOST`, because those variables were defined.

Comment: This is crazy. On it's own, any iteration of `process` is still undefined. But after using @Nagibaba answer, I can then only access values inside `process` while plain `process` stays undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Using yarn V1.22.15 applied this [solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880#issuecomment-1005409614)  which is working for me

Change the react-script version to **4.0.3** inside **package.json**.
Add this to **package.json** below the dependencies
`"resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" }`,
Install **react-error-overlay v6.0.9** inside your devDependencies.
**`yarn add --dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9`**
Remove your **node_modules** and **yarn.lock**.
Yarn install and check that works.

Answer (score 1):

For Vite Users in React

Instead of

```
process.env.REACT_APP_WHATEVER
```

use

```
import.meta.env.REACT_APP_WHATEVER
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue today (14th feb 22) using Docker containers for a ReactJS app and I solved it downgrading the react-scripts version to 4.0.3 and also installing react-error-overlay on version 6.0.9.
So the steps were:

1. Remove the **package-lock.json** file
2. Into the **package.json** file

   1. Replace the dependency **"react-scripts": "4.0.3"**
   2. Add react-error-overlay into the dev dependencies with **"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"**
3. Update npm: **npm update**

I hope it helps anybody to save some time,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For these who are using create-react-app with customize-cra you can use the Method 2 solution from @smac89 with addWebpackPlugin, this works for me.

react-scripts: 5.0.0
webpack: 5.64.4

```js
// config-overrides.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { override, addWebpackPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackPlugin(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      process: { env: {} },
    })
  )
);
```

this solution throws a warning on npm start but the application compiles right.

```
WARNING in DefinePlugin
Conflicting values for 'process.env'
```

This warning didn't brake anything but if anyone knows how to fix it please answer this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

in yarn.lock or package-lock.json file to find string

```
"react-error-overlay@npm:^6.0.9":
  version: 6.0.10 <-- here problem
  etc...
```

and replace to

```
react-error-overlay@^6.0.9:
  version "6.0.9"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-error-overlay/-/react-error-overlay-6.0.9.tgz#3c743010c9359608c375ecd6bc76f35d93995b0a"
  integrity sha512-nQTTcUu+ATDbrSD1BZHr5kgSD4oF8OFjxun8uAaL8RwPBacGBNPf/yAuVVdx17N8XNzRDMrZ9XcKZHCjPW+9ew==
```

saved file and run yarn install

Comment: Lock files are not meant to be edited manually. Don't do that! Use `resolutions` to force a specific version of `react-error-overlay`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in reactJs and I  fixed it with these steps:

Add to package.json:

1. "scripts": {
   "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
   }
2. "resolutions": {
   "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
   }

Comment: what exactly this npm-force package does? Does it make any breaking changes to the existing dependency tree?

Answer (score 0):

Moving to v5 of react scripts brought other issues for us, using the answer with the most votes also didn't work for us. Adding this to package.json did:

```
      "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a response to those who sees the `process is not defined` issue related to `index.html`, not the OP.

---

This might be due to that you are trying to use `process.env` directly in the `index.html` without using `<% %>`

Correct usage looks like this in `index.html`:

```
<% if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { %>
  <script>
    /* Disable Google Analytics locally */
    window["ga-disable-G-something"] = true;
  </script>
<% } %>
```

Incorrect usage (which might be your issue):

```
<script>
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  /* Disable Google Analytics locally */
  window["ga-disable-G-something"] = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

- react-error-overlay is an overlay that displays when there is a runtime error.

```
    npm install --save-dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9 --force
```

- Fix audit

```
    npm audit fix --force
    export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

For answers with Webpack, ex: Rafael Stone's.
Using only process work without any warning for me.

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    process: { },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was originating from the "path" module that was used in one of the components.
I resolved this by replacing the "path" with "path-browserify"

Answer (score 0):

For webpack:

```
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin')
const plugins = []

if (process.env.SERVE) {
  plugins.push(new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin())
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Upgrading react-scripts from v4 to "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
seem helped me