# TypeError: match.loader.options.plugins is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, craco

I am trying to use tailwindCSS in a ReactJS app

These are the scripts commands in `package.json` file

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

This is my `craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

When I am used `npm run start` command, I am facing this error

```
TypeError: match.loader.options.plugins is not a function
    at extendsPostcss (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\style\postcss.js:54:51)
    at overrideLoader (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\style\postcss.js:97:9)
    at C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\style\postcss.js:118:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at overridePostcss (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\style\postcss.js:117:17)
    at overrideStyle (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\style\style.js:9:25)
    at mergeWebpackConfig (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\merge-webpack-config.js:77:30)
    at overrideWebpackDev (C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\features\webpack\override.js:11:36)
    at C:\Development\Open Source\Learning Hub\react\node_modules\@craco\craco\scripts\start.js:27:5
```

Things that I have tried :

1. Reinstall `node_modules`

> Got this error, when I tried to do that

```
$ npm i @craco/craco
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: first-react-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   @craco/craco@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you solved your problem? There is a solution to the problem.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11777

> try to replace "postcss" with "postcssOptions" in craco config
> I had the same problem , this method works for me.

Comment: Took me a week to find this. Thanks !

Answer (score 23):

I replaced **postcss** with **postOptions** in carco.config.js
and it's working !

Comment: This answer is wrong. Using `postOptions` has the same effect as removing it altogether.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the Tailwind configuration from CRACO is not needed anymore.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11771#issuecomment-997217680

Look at Tailwind 3.0 install steps:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Answer (score 3):

craco config is no longer needed in tailwind docs however
in the solutions mentioned if you replace

**postcss** with **postOptions** on craco.config.js it will work too

Answer (score 3):

[WARNING] The most upvoted answer that suggesting changing the `postcss` to `postcssOptions` may not what you expect.

> try to replace "postcss" with "postcssOptions" in craco config

Currently, craco doesn't support `postcssOptions`, so changing the key just make craco ignore your configurations.

[patching craco](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11777#issuecomment-1200564270) would be better if you need custom configs.

Answer (score -1):

I replaced postcss with postOptions and it works for me