# Browser tab freeze on React and Angular save file (auto reload) but only after some action on component

Tags: reactjs, angular, ubuntu, freeze, reload

I have some strange problem with browser tab freeze when working with React and Angular projects. Browser tab freezes when I save some file but only if I do something like click on hamburger menu that shows another component or any action with components or browser tab.

Example:

-> I change something in component (added more text, changed some color)

-> saved file to auto reload

-> I can see changes on my browser tab (it looks like browser tab is not "refreshing" but changes that I've made are visible after save)

-> I add something to my component (anything)

-> I can see changes on my browser tab and everything is fine every time when I add or change something. BUT when I try to do some action like click on hamburger menu button, click on some nav button that changes component or even when I click "Toggle device toolbar" in browser dev tools then my browser tab freezes. Rendered component is showing with big delay, when I click some button then action is delayed and I have to close browser tab but it takes a while to close when I click on it to close it.

This problem appears in every browser I use (chrome, brave, firefox). My computer system is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I use VSCode for coding.

I'm not sure if this problem appears because of some IDE or project configuration. I think it's because something in Ubuntu but I don't know what is going on.

Edit.

It does not matter if it is big project full of code and logic or new one with simple one "Hello, World!" component - the problem appears always.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with chrome at the moment, thought I was going crazy. Haven't found a solution besides hard refresh of the window.

Comment: @Caliman this problem just disappeared when I work with Angular projects but still appears in React. I don't think I've updated any soft (browsers, node, os). Really strange.

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer fixed it for me. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70495171](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70495171)