# Process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

so i am implementing an auth page with  typescript React and firebase. I have stored my firebase credentials in my env file and i have referenced it using the process.env but everytime i try to visit my auth page i get the error process is not defined

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
require('dotenv').config();
import * as fs from 'fs'

import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain, 
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket, 
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId, 
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_measurementId,
};

// Initialize Firebase
 initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// getAnalytics(app);

export const auth = getAuth();
```

, attached below is my  firebase file.

Comment: Do you use `create-react-app`?

Comment: Where does this script run? You can't access `fs` and `dotenv` in the browser

Comment: in my App.tsx file

Comment: I got rid of the dotenv and fs but now the error points me to the firebase cred reference signaling process not defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368760/react-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined

Comment: thanks for this , solved it had to add process as a plugin in my webpack

Comment: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key), this is what i get now however

Comment: Did you tried to log the values to check if they are loaded correctly?

Comment: Gives me undefined but i have confirmed that my values are loaded correctly.

Comment: So how did you verified that they load?