# Uncaught ReferenceError wherein process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, json, process

I am trying to run my code and am receiving the below error in react console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Can anyone guide me to clear this error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please write the complete code here

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368760/react-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way to overcome from this error is by downgrade your react-scripts.
i followed this and it worked for me -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71083312/16244952

- Set "react-scripts": "4.0.3" in package.json
- Delete your lock file (yarn.lock or package-lock.json) and node_modules
- Run "npm install"

However got a new error and working on it :-) .