# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined (In React dev server)

Tags: reactjs, package.json, development-environment, uncaught-reference-error

**Title:** React Web App Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"

**Description:**

I'm currently in the process of developing a React web application, and I've encountered a perplexing issue that's brought my project to a halt. The error message I'm grappling with is as follows:

```bash
cli.js:88950  Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (cli.js:88950:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (cli.js:88984:30)
    at __webpack_require__2 (cli.js:22:30)
    at cli.js:68:18
    at node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js (cli.js:69:10)
    at __require2 (chunk-7REXU52E.js?v=0e1c7c04:19:50)
    at cli.js:153551:11

This perplexing error has arisen seemingly out of nowhere, and I've been grappling with it without success. In my quest to resolve it, I've diligently pursued various solutions, some of which have been recommended in a related Stack Overflow post.


My Current package.json:

json

{
  "name": "react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // A list of your dependencies...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // A list of your dev dependencies...
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}

I'm relatively new to React development, and I've been diligently working on this application for approximately two weeks. I find myself in a predicament, and I'm eager to surmount this obstacle to continue progressing with my project.

Additional Information:

    Operating system: Windows 10
    Development environment: WebStorm

Given the complexity and sudden appearance of this issue, I'm wondering if there's a way to revert to a previous state of my application when it was functioning correctly. In Windows, there's a system restore option that allows you to return to a previous point in time. Is there an equivalent in the world of React development?

Additionally, I've heard of using Git logs to potentially pinpoint when my application was last operational. How can I effectively utilize Git logs to identify and return to a stable state in my project's history? Any insights or guidance on these matters would be immensely appreciated.

Please provide me with detailed steps or suggestions to help me navigate through this challenging situation and get my React web app back on track. Your assistance means a great deal to me as I strive to complete my project.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368760/react-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined)

Comment: i tried that didnt work-.-