# Overriding NPM dependency of a dependency in package.json not working if the dependency was already installed

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I'm getting the following error when I try to import mongoose with TypeScript

```
node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:3309:5 - error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
```

Apparently this was fixed in mongodb 4.3.0, but mongoose uses mongodb 4.2.2

How could I force mongoose to use mongodb 4.3.0+ ?

I tried adding

```
  "overrides": {
    "mongoose": {
      "mongodb": "^4.3.0"
    }
  },
```

to package.json but it didn't fix the issue.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "reports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jestTestEnv.js"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --setupFiles ./jestTestEnv.js",
    "dev": "tsc && nodemon -r dotenv/config dist/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",

  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.1.0",
    "express-openid-connect": "^2.5.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^2.0.5",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "mongoose": {
      "mongodb": "^4.3.0"
    }
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-jwt": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution. There seems to be a bug here with NPM. Deleting both node_modules AND package-lock.json and then doing `npm install` fixes the issue. Deleting node_modules on its own doesn't fix it.

Comment: Deleting and rebuilding package-lock.json will forcibly update some of your dependencies unless they are pinned. Why is this a requirement?

Comment: issue is still open: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5850

Comment: This helped! In my case it was just deleting `package-lock.json` on its own that doesn't fix it. Deleting both helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am still encountering **[this bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5850)** on npm 10.2.5.

My workaround was to go **delete the entry** for the offending package from `package-lock.json` **by hand** before running `npm install`.

I **do not recommend** deleting the entire package-lock.json. Deleting node_modules should also not be necessary.

Comment: Anyone know of a good tool to automate removing all references to a specific package from package-lock.json?