# Overriding nested dependencies in Node.js projects to improve "npm audit" vulnerability report

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json, npm-audit

**I got some vulnerabilities resolved in my Node.js project by forcing some nested dependency updates but I need help understanding what's actually happening behind the scene of this improvement.**

Here is my original "**package.json**"

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "3.9.5",
  "description": "my application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "csv": "^6.0.1",
    "csv-stringify": "^6.0.1",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt": "1.4.1",
    "health-check": "1.0.3",
    "kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-oauth2": "^1.5.0",
    "sails": "^1.2.4",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^5.0.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.1",
    "sails-hook-uploads": "^0.4.3",
    "sails-mongo": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-redis": "^1.0.0",
    "my-inhouse-logger": "3.8.2",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  },
 "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev sails lift",
    "start-win": "sails lift",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:all": "npm run lint && npm run test:coverage",
    "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look good.'",
    "jest": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js",
    "jest-coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js --coverage --runInBand",
    "jest-no-coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js --runInBand",
    "jest-functional": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.functional.js --runInBand",
    "clean": "/bin/bash -c 'rm assets/js/* assets/css/* assets/fonts/* assets/index.html'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/myprofile/nbackend.git"
  },
  "author": "my name",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.14"
  }
}
```

When I did "**npm install**" and then "**npm audit**", I got

> 32 vulnerabilities (5 low, 8 moderate, 9 high, 10 critical)

Here is the full report

```
~/ideaprojects/myapp/backend$ npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
# npm audit report

acorn 5.5.0 - 5.7.3
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service in Acorn - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-6chw-6frg-f759
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/acorn

ajv <6.12.3
Severity: moderate
Prototype Pollution in Ajv - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v88g-cgmw-v5xw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/ajv
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/ajv
 eslint 4.2.0 - 5.0.0-rc.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of ajv
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/eslint

ansi-regex 3.0.0
Severity: moderate
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex

debug <2.6.9
Regular Expression Denial of Service in debug - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gxpj-cx7g-858c
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/debug
 mocha 0.6.0 - 6.2.2 || 7.0.0-esm1 - 7.1.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
 Depends on vulnerable versions of diff
 Depends on vulnerable versions of growl
 Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mocha

diff <3.5.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-h6ch-v84p-w6p9
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/diff
 mocha 0.6.0 - 6.2.2 || 7.0.0-esm1 - 7.1.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
 Depends on vulnerable versions of diff
 Depends on vulnerable versions of growl
 Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mocha

engine.io <4.0.0
Severity: high
Resource exhaustion in engine.io  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-j4f2-536g-r55m
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sails-hook-sockets@1.3.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/engine.io
 socket.io 1.0.0-pre - 2.4.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of engine.io
 node_modules/socket.io
   sails-hook-sockets *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   Depends on vulnerable versions of socket.io
   node_modules/sails-hook-sockets

getobject 0.1.0
Severity: critical
Prototype pollution vulnerability in 'getobject' - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-957j-59c2-j692
No fix available
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/getobject
 grunt-legacy-util <=2.0.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of getobject
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-util
   grunt <=1.2.1
   Depends on vulnerable versions of grunt-legacy-util
   node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt
     sails-hook-grunt *
     Depends on vulnerable versions of grunt
     node_modules/sails-hook-grunt

growl <1.10.0
Severity: critical
Command Injection in growl - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qh2h-chj9-jffq
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/growl
 mocha 0.6.0 - 6.2.2 || 7.0.0-esm1 - 7.1.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
 Depends on vulnerable versions of diff
 Depends on vulnerable versions of growl
 Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mocha

grunt <=1.2.1
Severity: critical
Arbitrary Code Execution in grunt - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m5pj-vjjf-4m3h
Depends on vulnerable versions of grunt-legacy-util
No fix available
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt
 sails-hook-grunt *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of grunt
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt

hosted-git-info <2.8.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in hosted-git-info - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-43f8-2h32-f4cj
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/hosted-git-info

json-schema <0.4.0
Severity: moderate
json-schema is vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-896r-f27r-55mw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/json-schema
 jsprim 0.3.0 - 1.4.1 || 2.0.0 - 2.0.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of json-schema
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/jsprim

lodash <=4.17.20
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p6mc-m468-83gw
Command Injection in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/lodash

minimist <=1.2.5
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-xvch-5gv4-984h
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vh95-rmgr-6w4m
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-vh95-rmgr-6w4m
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/minimist
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
 mkdirp 0.4.1 - 0.5.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of minimist
 node_modules/@sailshq/nedb/node_modules/mkdirp
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mkdirp
   @sailshq/nedb *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
   node_modules/@sailshq/nedb
     sails-disk >=2.1.1
     Depends on vulnerable versions of @sailshq/nedb
     node_modules/sails-disk
   mocha 0.6.0 - 6.2.2 || 7.0.0-esm1 - 7.1.0
   Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
   Depends on vulnerable versions of diff
   Depends on vulnerable versions of growl
   Depends on vulnerable versions of mkdirp
   node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/mocha

path-parse <1.0.7
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in path-parse - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hj48-42vr-x3v9
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/path-parse

redis 2.6.0 - 3.1.0
Potential exponential regex in monitor mode - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35q2-47q7-3pc3
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sails-hook-sockets@1.3.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/redis
node_modules/sails-redis/node_modules/redis
 @sailshq/socket.io-redis *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of redis
 node_modules/@sailshq/socket.io-redis
 machinepack-redis >=1.1.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of redis
 node_modules/machinepack-redis
 node_modules/sails-redis/node_modules/machinepack-redis
   sails *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   node_modules/sails
   sails-hook-sockets *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   Depends on vulnerable versions of socket.io
   node_modules/sails-hook-sockets
   sails-redis >=1.0.0-0
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   node_modules/sails-redis

sails *
Severity: moderate
Prototype Pollution in Sails.js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8v3j-jfg3-v3fv
Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
No fix available
node_modules/sails

trim-newlines <3.0.1
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service in trim-newlines - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7p7h-4mm5-852v
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/trim-newlines
 meow 3.4.0 - 5.0.0
 Depends on vulnerable versions of trim-newlines
 node_modules/meow
 node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/meow

websocket-extensions <0.1.4
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service in websocket-extensions (NPM package) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g78m-2chm-r7qv
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/websocket-extensions

32 vulnerabilities (5 low, 8 moderate, 9 high, 10 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
 npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
 npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

I added an "**overrides**" section to "**package.json**" to force some nested dependency update and improve the vulnerability report. Here is the new "**package.json**"

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "3.9.5",
  "description": "my application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "csv": "^6.0.1",
    "csv-stringify": "^6.0.1",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt": "1.4.1",
    "health-check": "1.0.3",
    "kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-oauth2": "^1.5.0",
    "sails": "^1.2.4",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^5.0.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.1",
    "sails-hook-uploads": "^0.4.3",
    "sails-mongo": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-redis": "^1.0.0",
    "my-inhouse-logger": "3.8.2",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "grunt": "1.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "sails-disk": "2.1.1",
    "minimist": "1.2.6",
    "node-notifier": "10.0.1",
    "trim-newlines": "4.0.2",
    "validator": "13.7.0",
    "getobject": "1.0.2",
    "grunt-legacy-util": "2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev sails lift",
    "start-win": "sails lift",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:all": "npm run lint && npm run test:coverage",
    "lint": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look good.'",
    "jest": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js",
    "jest-coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js --coverage --runInBand",
    "jest-no-coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.js --runInBand",
    "jest-functional": "NODE_ENV=test jest -c jest.config.functional.js --runInBand",
    "clean": "/bin/bash -c 'rm assets/js/* assets/css/* assets/fonts/* assets/index.html'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/myprofile/nbackend.git"
  },
  "author": "my name",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.14"
  }
}
```

But I still got the same vulnerability report.

Then in addition to "**overrides**" in "**package.json**", based on a [suggestion on another question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions/17423915#17423915), I also modified "**package-lock.json**" with just this block bellow that doesn't even look like a normal structure of what we usually have in "**package-lock.json**"

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sails-hook-grunt": {
      "version": "5.0.0",
      "from": "sails-hook-grunt@5.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "getobject": {
          "version": "1.0.2",
          "from": "getobject@1.0.2"
        },
        "grunt-legacy-util": {
          "version": "2.0.1",
          "from": "grunt-legacy-util@2.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I run "**npm install**" and then "**npm audit**", I get a much better report like this

> 8 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)

Here is the full improved report

```
~/ideaprojects/myapp/backend$ npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
# npm audit report

engine.io <4.0.0
Severity: high
Resource exhaustion in engine.io  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-j4f2-536g-r55m
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sails-hook-sockets@1.3.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/engine.io
 socket.io 1.0.0-pre - 2.4.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of engine.io
 node_modules/socket.io
   sails-hook-sockets *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   Depends on vulnerable versions of socket.io
   node_modules/sails-hook-sockets

redis 2.6.0 - 3.1.0
Potential exponential regex in monitor mode - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35q2-47q7-3pc3
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install sails-redis@0.10.7, which is a breaking change
node_modules/redis
node_modules/sails-redis/node_modules/redis
 @sailshq/socket.io-redis *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of redis
 node_modules/@sailshq/socket.io-redis
 machinepack-redis >=1.1.1
 Depends on vulnerable versions of redis
 node_modules/machinepack-redis
 node_modules/sails-redis/node_modules/machinepack-redis
   sails *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   node_modules/sails
   sails-hook-sockets *
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   Depends on vulnerable versions of socket.io
   node_modules/sails-hook-sockets
   sails-redis >=1.0.0-0
   Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
   node_modules/sails-redis

sails *
Severity: moderate
Prototype Pollution in Sails.js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8v3j-jfg3-v3fv
Depends on vulnerable versions of machinepack-redis
No fix available
node_modules/sails

8 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
 npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

If I either remove the "**overrides**" section in "**package.json**" or not modify "**package-lock.json**" like I mentioned above I won't get the vulnerability report improved. Looks like I need  both.

Even if I do "**npm install**" again, all the vulnerabilities will get back into the report. And I really don't understand why.

But the main confusion is: how that modification I made to "**package-lock.json**" helps with a better vulnerability report. I know "**npm install**" regenerates "**package-lock.json**" and what I added there should be lost. Does "**npm install**" consider the dependency I manually added to "**package-lock.json**" before regenerating it? And why this should matter when I have all the dependencies overridden in my "**package.json**".

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes, "It's not the things that you *don't* know that get you into trouble. It's the things that you know for sure but that just ain't so.". In your case:

> I know "npm install" regenerates "package-lock.json"

That just ain't true! `package-lock.json` is only generated if it doesn't exist or when changes are made to the actually installed packages. It's best to think of it as overriding `package.json` most of the time and I think that's exactly what is happening in your case.

That said, it might be enough to add the `overrides` section, delete `package-lock.json`, and re-run `npm install` to have it be regenerated with, hopefully, the new overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I deleted `packag-lock.json` and even `node_modules` folder and then did `npm install` while I had the `overrides` in `package.json`. But I got all the vulnerabilities back and it looks like I'm not getting nested dependencies overridden when I don't modify `package-lock.json`. And I get `package-lock.json` regenerated even if there is already one.

Comment: ok and just to check: you are using npm v8 right?

Comment: Yes, npm 8.5.5.

Comment: what does `npm ls grunt` give you after you do the fresh `npm install` with no package-lock but with the overrides?

Comment: ```my-app@3.9.5 /home/alireza/ideaprojects/my-app/backend
├── grunt@1.4.1
└─┬ sails-hook-grunt@5.0.0
  └── grunt@1.0.4 invalid: "1.4.1" from node_modules/sails-hook-grunt

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: grunt@1.0.4 /home/alireza/ideaprojects/my-app/backend/node_modules/sails-hook-grunt/node_modules/grunt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alireza/.npm/_logs/2022-04-08T02_35_55_546Z-debug-0.log```

Comment: There it seems to point out the issue: it seems that `sails-hook-grunt` really doesn't allow anything but grunt `1.0.4`.

Comment: grunt `1.0.4` works. So I changed grunt version in `package.json` and got a better `npm ls grunt`: ```my-app@3.9.5 /home/alireza/ideaprojects/my-app/backend
├── grunt@1.0.4
└─┬ sails-hook-grunt@5.0.0
 └── grunt@1.0.4```.  But I get all the vulnerabilities back when I do `npm audit`. Again, if I modify `pakage-lock.json` like I mentioned in the question, then I get the improved vulnerability report and `npm ls grunt` gives me this:

Comment: ```my-app@3.9.5 /home/alireza/ideaprojects/my-app/backend
├── grunt@1.0.4
└─┬ sails-hook-grunt@5.0.0
 ├─┬ grunt-babel@7.0.0
 │ └── grunt@1.0.4 deduped
 ├─┬ grunt-contrib-clean@1.0.0
 │ └── grunt@1.0.4 deduped
 ├─┬ grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
 │ └── grunt@1.0.4 deduped
 └── grunt@1.0.4 deduped```

Comment: Looks like it does the trick when I put this into `package-lock.json`: ```{
  "dependencies": {
    "sails-hook-grunt": {
      "version": "5.0.0",
      "from": "sails-hook-grunt@5.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "getobject": {
          "version": "1.0.2",
          "from": "getobject@1.0.2"
        },
        "grunt-legacy-util": {
          "version": "2.0.1",
          "from": "grunt-legacy-util@2.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```. But why? I don't get how this helps but it does!