# how can I update to specific version of child dependency on a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, version, vue-tel-input

npm version: 7.24.2

someone know update a child dependency, I have the dependency:

- vue-tel-input

and this dependency has the dependency libphonenumber-js with version: ^1.9.6

I want to update this libphonenumber-js to ^1.10.12
I already tried with:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json?fbclid=IwAR2lAcPyu2XTTR5srKIEOpr1v8HM6UZL66WC42IG_8c3UU_u_vXeSPAL8J8#overrides
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524488

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that easily with your current setup.

you can either update to `npm v8.3`+, which supports `overrides` or use `yarn` with `resolutions`

more info:

overrides(npm):
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

package.json

```json
  "overrides": {
    "vue-tel-input": {
      "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.12"
    }
  }
```

resolutions(yarn):
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

package.json

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.12"
  }
```

---

alternatively, you can manage the `package-lock.json` file manually to define the version

```json
"vue-tel-input": {
  "version": "5.11.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-tel-input/-/vue-tel-input-5.11.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-kw13LdbnSH+Zk5Qb06vflG7Abu6QsM1cQyKvTA9T4kaZeARvyvKo9YZmziy7WiSuar932DWRjGI0SJnban4a2A==",
  "requires": {
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  }
},
```

you might be able to change `"libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.6"` to use `^1.10.12`

but wanted to point out that when I did a fresh install, it did install `1.10.12`

```json
"node_modules/libphonenumber-js": {
  "version": "1.10.12",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/libphonenumber-js/-/libphonenumber-js-1.10.12.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-xTFBs3ipFQNmjCUkDj6ZzRJvs97IyazFHBKWtrQrLiYs0Zk0GANob1hkMRlQUQXbJrpQGwnI+/yU4oyD4ohvpw=="
},
```

Because `^` will update to the latest **minor** version (2nd number), it should use a specific version, so in this case, because you're going from `1.9.*` to `1.10.*` and using `^1.9.6` you may be able to just remove your lock file and re-install to get `1.10.12`

Comment: yep, but the condition of the project dont let me to update to npm v8+

Comment: you can also edit the `package.lock` manually 

Comment: but the current library, that in this case is `vue-tel-input`, doesnt have the last version of `libphonenumber-js`

Comment: looks like `libphonenumber-js` will install with v `1.10.12`, so you could try removing the lock file and doing `npm i` to re-install. If the version or locks are cached in ci/cd pipeline, you might need to clear the cache.

Comment: something weird, I just to run `npm cache clean -f` and also I re run `npm i` but I still getting the same problem with the library.

but also, something interesting, I just did a test to update the version of `npm` to `8+`  with json of `overrides` and even, I still gettin the problem with the version of `libphonenumber-js`

Comment: can you clarify what that problem is? maybe the library version installed is fine‍♂️