# NPM Override does not appear to be working

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to fix an issue related to worker version between the versions of pdfjs-dist used by my package pdf-viewer-reactjs@2.2.3 and package react-pdf@5.4.0.

I came across the option( [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions) ) to override the version used by pdf-viewer-reactjs@2.2.3 which is "pdfjs-dist": "^2.6.347" by adding the following in my package.json

"overrides": {
"pdf-viewer-reactjs": {
"pdfjs-dist": "$pdfjs-dist"
}
}

Example of current package.json

[image]

My questions are:

1.Why doesnt override work?When using npm install the version used and installed in both my package-lock.json and in the node_module is still 2.6.347(despite npm list saying otherwise). Should it not be using this version(located in my dependencies section in package-json)?

[image]

2.Why does npm list --depth=1 show me this:

[image]

It shows that the sub-dependency used is the correct version however, if i check the package.json(which is auto generated when running npm install) in node_modules for pdf-viewer-reactjs it is still 2.6.347

[image]