# Yarn 3.3.1 : how to upgrade all instances of a package?

Tags: package, upgrade, yarn-v3

Hi everybody 
I don't really now if these are called "instances" of a package...anyway, my problem is this:
if I run `yarn npm audit` it shows me a problem with the package *trim-newlines* and suggests me to upgrade it to a version >=3.0.1 After the upgrade (with `yarn up trim-newlines`), I run `npm ls trim-newlines` and this is the output:

```
├─┬ lerna@3.22.1
│ └─┬ @lerna/version@3.22.1
│   └─┬ @lerna/conventional-commits@3.22.0
│     ├─┬ conventional-changelog-core@3.2.3
│     │ ├─┬ conventional-changelog-writer@4.1.0
│     │ │ └─┬ meow@8.1.2
│     │ │   └── trim-newlines@3.0.1
│     │ ├─┬ conventional-commits-parser@3.2.4
│     │ │ └─┬ meow@8.1.2
│     │ │   └── trim-newlines@3.0.1
│     │ └─┬ get-pkg-repo@1.4.0
│     │   └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│     │     └── trim-newlines@1.0.0
│     └─┬ conventional-recommended-bump@5.0.1
│       └─┬ meow@4.0.1
│         └── trim-newlines@2.0.0
└── trim-newlines@4.0.2
```

So it looks like there are multiple versions of it. I managed to upgrade the bottom one to latest version, but how do I upgrade the others?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions/70396201#70396201 Seems relevant. You can use `overrides` in your `package.json`, though there seem to be a few quirks, as mentioned in the replies to that post.

Comment: @SteveE I tried it but I get `npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: trim-newlines@2.0.0 C:\path_to\node_modules\meow\node_modules\trim-newlines
npm ERR! invalid: trim-newlines@3.0.1 C:\path_to\node_modules\conventional-changelog-writer\node_modules\trim-newlines
npm ERR! invalid: trim-newlines@3.0.1 C:\path_to\node_modules\conventional-commits-parser\node_modules\trim-newlines
npm ERR! invalid: trim-newlines@1.0.0 C:\path_to\node_modules\get-pkg-repo\node_modules\trim-newlines`

Comment: You may be able to try some of the suggestions [here](https://sebhastian.com/npm-err-code-elsproblems/) in the **ELSPROBLEMS: Invalid Package** section, though again, even if you manage to upgrade / override it, there's a chance the other dependencies you have may just not work at all, given how far apart the version they're expecting is form the version you'd be providing.