# Electron Project not working on New Mac Air 2

Tags: .net, electron, npm-install

I am trying to clone a project from this repo: https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/electron-cgi-calculator-demo. But once I do npm install, I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/mohitbhavsar/Desktop/electron-cgi-calculator-demo-

master/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node install.js
Downloading tmp-1202-0-electron-v4.0.4-darwin-arm64.zip
npm ERR! Error: GET https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v4.0.4/electron-v4.0.4-darwin-arm64.zip returned 404
npm ERR! /Users/mohitbhavsar/Desktop/electron-cgi-calculator-demo-master/node_modules/electron/install.js:49
npm ERR!   throw err
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Failed to find Electron v4.0.4 for darwin-arm64 at https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v4.0.4/electron-v4.0.4-darwin-arm64.zip
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/mohitbhavsar/Desktop/electron-cgi-calculator-demo-master/node_modules/nugget/index.js:169:61)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at Request.onRequestResponse (/Users/mohitbhavsar/Desktop/electron-cgi-calculator-demo-master/node_modules/request/request.js:1066:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:693:27)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
npm ERR!     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.12.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mohitbhavsar/.npm/_logs/2023-02-06T17_07_35_382Z-debug-0.log
```

Next, when I do npm start, the project opens up but I an unable to click anything and no changes are made to the app. What should I do?

I installed electron and electron-cgi packages as well but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron,

> macOS (High Sierra and up): Electron provides 64-bit Intel and ARM binaries for macOS. Apple Silicon support was added in Electron 11.

So use a much more recent version of Electron.

You'll have to ask the project owner nicely or probably fork it and change it yourself.

Alternatively, you could try [overriding the dependency version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396201).