# How to override a dependency version when installing a package globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the [`vcremote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcremote) npm package which contains a command line tool that I need to run regularly via shell. Therefore, I attempt to install it globally using the below command:

```bash
npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote
```

Unfortunately, the installation fails on my machine because an indirect dependency package is outdated and needs to be replaced with a newer version. The dependency tree looks as follows:

```
vcremote
  |
  +--vcremote-lib
       |
       +--ios-deploy
```

I would need to override the version of `ios-deploy` while installing `vcremote`.

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15806152) SO post that asks almost the same. As pointed out by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396201), I have tried to use [`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) but that seems to be ignored. I assume it is related to the fact that I try to install the package globally which means there really isn't a packages.json file.

Is there a way to override the version of `ios-deploy` while installing `vcremote` globally?