# How do I override multiple nested NPM dependency in different versions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ice

i'm sorry my English is not good

my NPM dependency

```
dependency tree

+-- react-dev-inspector@1.9.0
| +-- react-dev-utils@12.0.1
| | +-- loader-utils@3.2.0 <---this


+-- ice.js@1.18.5
| +-- @alib/build-scripts@0.1.32
| | +-- react-dev-utils@9.1.0
| | | -- loader-utils@1.2.3 <---this
```

i need to override for fix loophole detection：

```
dependency tree

+-- react-dev-inspector@1.9.0
| +-- react-dev-utils@12.0.1
| | +-- loader-utils@3.2.1 <---this


+-- ice.js@1.18.5
| +-- @alib/build-scripts@0.1.32
| | +-- react-dev-utils@9.1.0
| | | -- loader-utils@1.4.2 <---this
```

my version:
node: v12.18.0
npm: 6.14.4

I search [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions) ，but that can't resolve my question

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade react-dev-utils to same 12.0.1 versions? This version was released 2 years age, it is stable and dual-use loader-utils@3.2.1.

```
dependency tree

+-- react-dev-inspector@1.9.0
| +-- react-dev-utils@12.0.1
| | +-- loader-utils@3.2.1

+-- ice.js@1.18.5
| +-- @alib/build-scripts@0.1.32
| | +-- react-dev-utils@12.0.1
| | | -- loader-utils@3.2.1
```

If you cannot upgrade react-dev-utils to the same version, I believe ice.js is not widely used, can you use another tool instead of ice.js?

Comment: I can't instead of ice.js, and can't upgrade react-dev-utils, because this two dependency  is a small portion in my need to fix loophole detection

Comment: I think if you use different react-dev-utils, and it must use different loader-utils. So can you upgrade you nodejs and npm version to npm v8.3 (released with Node.js 16) and use "overrides" in your package.json?

Comment: Nodejs V12.18.0 is too old and is hard to fix some bugs.

Comment: If I upgrage my node.js to 16, my project will be not work orz