# How to override a dependency version in npm global install?

Tags: npm, puppeteer, pandoc, mermaid

I'm trying to install mermaid-filter (mermaid for pandoc), and the installation fails because it relies on an old version of puppeteer. The old version of puppeteer installation fails because it is trying to download a version of chromium which is now 404.

I've tried wiping out my npm_cache and then installing puppeteer first in the hope that when attempting to install mermaid filter it would just use the existing version, but this made no difference.

How to I tell npm to use a different version of puppeteer when installing that package globally? Or is there some way to fake it with a local install and then I could maybe get that into the path somehow so pandoc would work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo That advice does not appear to apply to global installs.